# Como puedo asignar un textarea a un option value?

Tags: html, formularios

Tengo un problema que no logro resolver y es que tengo un formulario en `html` y tengo un `optgroup`, el cual se encarga de que en un despegable salga las opciones que yo ponga...

Pero ahora lo que quiero es que me salga un `textarea` según el `option value` que clickee. Sé que se puede hacer pero no encuentro manera y ademas también ponerle caracteres en el `textarea`, según seleccione salga una plantilla u otra.

Adjunto el código.

Muchas Gracias!!!

```html
<form action="send_email.php" method="post"><a target="_blank">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
      <label for="name">Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
      <label for="lastname">Apellidos</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
      <label for="phone">Telefono de contacto</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
      <label for="email">Correo electronico</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control ">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
      <label for="message">Escriba su mensaje</label>
      <select name ="plantillas" input type="text" name="texto" id="texto" class="form-control ">
        <option selected value="0" onclick="myFunction()"> Elige una opción </option>
        <optgroup label="Sugerencia:"> </optgroup>
        <option value="1" onclick="myFunction()">Sugerencia</option>
        <optgroup label="Pedido:"></optgroup>
        <option value="2" onclick="myFunction()">Pedido</option>
      </select><br>
      <textarea name="textarea" value ="plantillas" name="message" id="mensaje" class="form-control " cols="30" rows="8" placeholder="Comparte tu sugerencias" hidden></textarea>
      <textarea name="textarea" value ="plantillas" name="message" id="pedido" class="form-control " cols="30" rows="8" placeholder="Haz tu Pedido" hidden></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
      <script>

  function myFunction(){
    var lista = document.getElementById("texto");
    var indiceSeleccionado = lista.selectedIndex;
    var listaint = document.getElementById("texto").options[1];
    var textoSeleccionado = listaint.text;
    var listaint2 = document.getElementById("texto").options[2];
    if (indiceSeleccionado == 0) {
      var textarea_mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
      var textarea_pedido = document.getElementById("pedido");
      alert("Selecciona una opcion");
      textarea_mensaje.style.display = 'none';
      textarea_pedido.style.display = 'none';

    }
    if (indiceSeleccionado == 1) {
      var textarea_mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
      //mostrar elemento
      textarea_mensaje.style.display = 'block';
      var textareaSeleccionado = textarea_mensaje.text;
      var valorSeleccionado = textarea_mensaje.value;
      var textarea_pedido = document.getElementById("pedido");
      //ocultar elemento
      textarea_pedido.style.display = 'none';
      var textareaSeleccionado2 = textarea_pedido.text;
      var valorSeleccionado2 = textarea_pedido.value;
    }
    if (indiceSeleccionado == 2) {
      var textarea_mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
      textarea_mensaje.style.display = 'none';
      var textareaSeleccionado = textarea_mensaje.text;
      var valorSeleccionado = textarea_mensaje.value;
      var textarea_pedido = document.getElementById("pedido");
      textarea_pedido.style.display = 'block';
      var textareaSeleccionado2 = textarea_pedido.text;
      var valorSeleccionado2 = textarea_pedido.value;
    }
    else{
      
    }
 //var indiceSeleccionado = lista.selectedIndex;
  //alert(lista);
}
 
</script> 
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Codigo pegado de la pagina de prueba y que no aparecen los textarea, no entiendo el porque...

```html
<form action="send_email.php" method="post"><a target="_blank">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                      <input type="text" name="name"id="name" class="form-control ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="lastname">Apellidos</label>
                      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="phone">Telefono de contacto</label>
                      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="email">Correo electronico</label>
                      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control ">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="message">Escriba su mensaje</label>
                      <select name ="plantillas" input type="text" name="texto" id="texto" class="form-control ">
                       <option selected value="0" onclick="myFunction()"> Elige una opción </option>
            <optgroup label="Sugerencia:"> </optgroup>
           <option value="1" onclick="myFunction()">Sugerencia</option>
           <optgroup label="Pedido:"></optgroup>
           <option value="2" onclick="myFunction()">Pedido</option>
      </select><br>
      <textarea name="Sugerencia" value ="plantillas" name="message" id="mensaje" class="form-control " cols="30" rows="8" placeholder="Comparte tu sugerencias" hidden></textarea>
                      <textarea name="Pedido" value ="plantillas" name="message" id="pedido" class="form-control " cols="30" rows="8" placeholder="Haz tu Pedido" hidden></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                     <script>

  function myFunction(){
    var lista = document.getElementById("texto");
    var indiceSeleccionado = lista.selectedIndex;
    var listaint = document.getElementById("texto").options[1];
    var textoSeleccionado = listaint.text;
    var listaint2 = document.getElementById("texto").options[2];
    if (indiceSeleccionado == 0) {
      var textarea_mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
      var textarea_pedido = document.getElementById("pedido");
      alert("Selecciona una opcion");

    }
    if (indiceSeleccionado == 1) {
      var textarea_mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
      //mostrar elemento
      textarea_Seleccionado.style.display = 'block';
      var textareaSeleccionado = textarea_mensaje.text;
      var valorSeleccionado = textarea_mensaje.value;
      var textarea_pedido = document.getElementById("pedido");
      alert("Selecciona una opcion1");
      //ocultar elemento
      textarea_pedido.style.display = 'none';
      var textareaSeleccionado2 = textarea_pedido.text;
      var valorSeleccionado2 = textarea_pedido.value;
    }
    if (indiceSeleccionado == 2) {
      var textarea_mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
      textarea_mensaje.style.display = 'none';
      var textareaSeleccionado = textarea_mensaje.text;
      var valorSeleccionado = textarea_mensaje.value;
      var textarea_pedido = document.getElementById("pedido");
      textarea_pedido.style.display = 'block';
      var textareaSeleccionado2 = textarea_pedido.text;
      var valorSeleccionado2 = textarea_pedido.value;
    }
    else{
      
    }
 //var indiceSeleccionado = lista.selectedIndex;
  //alert(lista);
}
 
</script> 

                      <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary"></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ello debes usar `JavaScript` o `jQuery` y cambiar un par de cosas en tu código:

- Sacar los `textarea` fuera del `select`.
- Asignar `id` diferente a cada elemento, ya que solo debe existir un único `id` en todo el DOM.
- Agregar la propiedad `hidden` para que estén ocultos por defecto.
- Creo que sobra la etiqueta `<a target="_blank">`

Con `jQuery` lo que haces es mostrar u ocultar el `textarea` según la selección del usuario. *el código está comentado para que entiendas cada línea.*

```js
//cuando detecte el cambio en el select
$('select').change(function(){
  //asigna el valor a la variable opcion
  var opcion = $(this).val();
  //si la opción es 1
  if (opcion == 1) {
    //muestra el text area de sugerencia
    $('#sugerencia').prop('hidden', false);
    //oculta el text area de pedido
    $('#pedido').prop('hidden', true);
  //en caso contrario
  } else {
    //muestra el text area de pedido
    $('#pedido').prop('hidden', false);
    //oculta el text area de sugerencia
    $('#sugerencia').prop('hidden', true);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="send_email.php" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
      <label for="name">Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" name="name"id="name" class="form-control ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
      <label for="lastname">Apellidos</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
      <label for="phone">Telefono de contacto</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
      <label for="email">Correo electronico</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control ">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
      <label for="message">Escriba su mensaje</label>
      <select name ="plantillas" input type="text" name="texto" id="texto" class="form-control ">
        <option selected value="0"> Elige una opción </option>
        <optgroup label="Sugerencia:"> </optgroup>
        <option value="1">Sugerencia</option>
        <optgroup label="Pedido:"></optgroup>
        <option value="2">Pedido</option>
      </select><br>
      <textarea name="Sugerencia" value ="plantillas" name="message" id="sugerencia" class="form-control " cols="30" rows="8" placeholder="Comparte tu sugerencias" hidden></textarea>
      <textarea name="Pedido" value ="plantillas" name="message" id="pedido" class="form-control " cols="30" rows="8" placeholder="Haz tu Pedido" hidden></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
      <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Cualquier inquietud, comenta.

Comment: Primero muchas gracias por el aporte ya tengo el html modificado y corregido y correcto lo que pasa que jQuery no lo he utilizado nunca....Javascript si he tocado algo, si me lo podrias pasar el aporte pero pasado en lenguaje Javascritp seria de gran ayuda para un mayor entendimiento, jQuery no conozco nada y me pierdo...Perdona por mi torpeza ...

Comment: Ya esta resuelto muchas Graciasss

Comment: Perdón por tardar en responder, estuve fuera un par de días... Me alegra que te sirviera.